# xterm keep page from less in terminal after exit

Tags: linux, bash, xterm, less-unix

I often view files using less and want to remember what i have just seen in the file.  However when I quit less by pressing the q key my xterm window removes the page of less showing the file and only shows my command prompt.

How do I keep the less output on my terminal when I quit?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

less -X

Use the -X option from the less man page described below:

```
   -X or --no-init
          Disables  sending  the  termcap  initialization and deinitialization strings to the terminal.
          This is sometimes desirable if the deinitialization string does something  unnecessary,  like
          clearing the screen.
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if you are using [xterm](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.html) (rather than some other program), the choice of whether to honor alternate-screen escape sequences can be done readily using a menu selection **Enable Alternate Screen Switching** (or resource setting).  The `less` option does not apply to other programs such as `vi`.

In the manual, this is the **titeInhibit**, named after the termcap settings

- ti (terminal initialization)
- te (terminal ending)

and in the FAQ, this is [Why doesn't the screen clear when running vi?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_tite).