# git log/show etc. replaces the terminal screen

Tags: git, terminal, git-log, oh-my-zsh

I recently started to use `zsh` (oh-my-zsh, without customizations) on iTerm2. But, I'm having a trouble in `git log` or `git show`.

Previously, for example, the `git log` results were just a part of the terminal, just like `ls -l` result. After quitting `git log` by pressing `q` key, the result was remained in the terminal screen. I was able to pick some hash id easily.

However, the current problem is that `git log` (or `git show`) results replace the screen. So, after quitting `git log`, the terminal completely removes all `git` results and returns to the original screen. This behavior is like `vim`.

This behavior is the same even with `bash` or Mac's default terminal app. This is not a problem of `--no-pager`.

Any helps would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have `PAGER` set to anything? `PAGER=/bin/cat` or `PAGER=/usr/bin/less` seem like sane options. Default in my environment is to operator like `/usr/bin/less`, when the value is not set.

Comment: Thanks. `which $PAGER` gives `/usr/bin/less`..

Comment: Does /bin/cat have the behavior you want?

Comment: sounds like a `less` issue discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977781/xterm-keep-page-from-less-in-terminal-after-exit

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Can you try with:

```
git config --global --replace-all core.pager "less -F -X"
```

From "How do I prevent git diff from using a pager?":

> passing the `-F` option to less causes it to quit if the content is less than one screen, **however after doing so the screen is reset and you end up not seeing the content**, the **`-X` option does away with that behaviour**.

Comment: Thank you so much. It fixes the problem! Wow, so many hidden options and weird behaviors.

Answer (score 59):

oh-my-zsh executes `less` with `-R` flag, You may run `unset LESS` to fallback to default behaviour.

If you want to make this change persistent, put this command to `.zshrc`.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I also think it's change from oh-my-szh because `git log` still working fine in normal bash shell

Comment: You may dig into .zshrc and other zsh settings to set correct flags for `less`.

Comment: I think this is the better answer, as it mitigates the root cause. Changing `git` config did not help me with e.g. `aws` aliases.

Comment: I much prefer this method. Just finally upgraded to Catalina and this whole 'new page' thing was bugging me! :D

Comment: combining these two answers, you can also set `LESS=-RFX`

Comment: My saviour! I have almost set down to Tony Buzan's "Use Your Memory" again to help me memorize those SHA1s. Now I can again just copy them 